# How do I use bokeh to plot multiple histograms that overlap, colored by a certain column value?

Tags: python, plot, histogram, bokeh

I have a csv file that I read and load as a dataframe. A column that's EC has 4 different values (0,1,2 and 3). I want to plot a 4 hitograms that represent the distribution of a column called 'size' and they should be colored differently based on the value of EC.

I could do that with seaborn and  matplotlib but now I have to use bokeh which I have no clue how to use. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's not enough information presented. It's not quite clear what you actually want (the description of the data is not completely clear) and more generally, Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. It's always better to make an attempt and then present the code you used, so that you can get help with *specific issues in existing code*.

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried. Examples of grid layouts with Bokeh will be a good starting point if you haven't seen them already: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/layout.html